# Most secure way to temporarily store a password

Tags: security, web, encryption, passwords

I have the following use case:

My web application is used for creating prescriptions. When I send the prescription creation request to the government API it is signed with the current user's certificate. The certificate is stored on the application server and is encrypted with a password which only the user knows.
Users want to be able to store their password in my app temporarily so that they don't need to paste it in for each prescription they create.

What would be the most secure way to store this password? Couple of ideas:

1. Local storage in the browser.

   Bad because anyone with an access to the user's device can see the
   password even if they're not logged in. Also if the app is not running I have no way to clear the password if the desired storage time expires.
2. Frontend app memory.

   Bad because if user refreshes the page or opens another tab the stored password is gone.
3. Backend, in database

   This sounds like the best option because I can encrypt the password. Is it even worth encrypting though? I would have to encrypt it with some key stored on the same machine so if someone gains access to this machine the encryption doesn't matter because they would be able to decrypt it quite easily.

Comment: You are missing session storage in the list. Any particular reason for that? Session usually get cleaned up automatically eventually.

Comment: @Peter Do you mean storing it in a browser cookie or on the server side?

Comment: I assumed you have that already in place. If you don't then an encrypted cookie with frequently rotated keys is a viable option.

Comment: A note about local storage: an attacker does not need physical access, any JS running on the page can access it (including potential XSS, supply chain attack and so on...), so it is strongly advised to not store sensitive data here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the password encryption key and the encrypted password:

1. Generate and store a random key (and nonce / salt)
2. Encrypt the password (e.g. `AES-256-GCM`) with the random key
3. Store the encrypted password on your backend
4. Send the random key with the request to temporarily decrypt the password
5. Delete the encrypted password on the backend when the session expires

That way:

- The random key stored in the browser can only be used within the current user session and is useless on its own
- The encrypted password on your backed can only be used with the random key stored in the browser and is useless on its own

Comment: This looks like really good idea. Thanks.
I guess I would have to make sure that the key used to decrypt the password sent in an HTTP request isn't logged anywhere because this could nullify any efforts to make storing these passwords in a secure way.